# LinkButton and jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=btnDelete]").removeAttr("onclick");
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            title: "Confirmation",
            width: 350,
            height: 160,
            buttons: [
                {
                    id: "Yes",
                    text: "Yes",
                    click: function () {
                      $("[id*=btnDelete]").attr("rel", "delete");
                        $("[id*=btnDelete]").click();
                    }
                },
                {
                    id: "No",
                    text: "No",
                    click: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
      $("[id*=btnDelete]").click(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("rel") != "delete") {
                $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                return false;
            } else {
                __doPostBack(this.name, '');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete"   CssClass="ui-icon" runat="server"  OnClick="DeleteRecord" >
                  <div  class="icon-lougou"></div><br /> <span>logout</span></asp:LinkButton>
```

the dialog is show put not firing on onclick DeleteRecored can not
firing the onlick after show  dialog

the dialog is show put not firing on onclick DeleteRecored can not
firing the onlick after show  dialog

Comment: Your code does not compile

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OnClientClick` property:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete"   CssClass="ui-icon" runat="server"  OnClientClick="DeleteRecord();" >
```

As per the docs:

> The `OnClientClick` property is used to sets a client side script to
> be run when the Button control is clicked